# How can I get trid of the "expected and identifier" error?

Tags: flutter

I am learning flutter via video tutorials and I typed the code just as the instructor did but his code ran and mine didn't. I keep getting the "expected and identifier" error. Here is the code:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihfGC.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You have a `.` after `Colors.blue` instead of a `,` (Period instead of comma).

Change the period to a comma, and that should fix your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try to change

```
color: Colors.blue.
```

to

```
color: Colors.blue,
```